# When should we work on GC optimization?

Tags: java, optimization, garbage-collection

So, I've learnt about how GC works and how can I monitor it via `VisualVM`, but my question is about why we should ever perform GC optimization? In our web project (JSF/Spring/Hibernate) we haven't thought about this kind of optimization. Isn't it important and where such an optimization may be important?

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: @gnat What kind of researche did you expect? I don't ever know why we should perform that optimization.

Comment: did you check [meta guidance](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6560/31260) referred in prior comment?

Comment: Does your project currently suffer from one or more symptoms of negative effects from GC? Do you have some performance monitoring (e.g. response times) on production environments? In other words, do you know you have a problem with GC to begin with? Can you avoid the problem by throwing money at it (either scaling out, or over-provisioning memory on a single server)? Etc.

Comment: If there is indeed a problem, it is more likely to affect production environments because it is highly utilized compared to development (or test) environments, unless a proper stress test is performed. In this case, the "operations" people (which we call "I. T." people, which stands for information technology) will be the first ones to know. If you never have to talk with IT people (or if they're not allowed to talk to you, then you may never know that a problem exists in production environment.

Comment: This may sounds like a relatively naive answer but I would say, as long as you do not measure any big performance issues, I would not bother that much. Especially when we look at web applications my first bet would be to improve speed on the client. On the server side, the GC would be one of the last things I would take a look at compared to the 'upper-level code' like services.

Comment: If you want to save time in GC, first save time in `new`. [*This illustrates the method I use, which works in any language.*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/927773/23771) You could well find that you are doing `new`s that could be avoided, such as by re-using old objects rather than making new ones.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv Regarding research, if you've learned how GC works, then at least some of the factors that affect GC collection time and frequency should be clear to you. It's not even clear whether you're asking about optimizing your code or optimizing the garbage collector. The question looks like it's offloaded most of the hard thinking to the everyone else.

Answer (score 5):

When your project experiences performance problems. 
You can fine tune the garbage collection algorithm used, how often to run it - depending on you performance requirements. Let's say you have lots of RAM on your server but not too much CPU power, then you want to delay garbage collector as much as possible to night time for example. And so on.

Answer (score 3):

*(Disclaimer: I do not work on server-side backends, and I do not have any [IT operational](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_technology_operations) experience. My answer below is only from architectural theory and not from experience.)*

---

If you are unsure of what to do, *try* the following order of precedence. 
*(The first two steps has nothing to do with GC, but if those two aren't taken care of, talking about GC optimization is pointless.)*
<sub>but please do not follow blindly; as I said I have no real experience in this.</sub>

- First of all, you should find and eliminate memory leaks in your code base.
- Next, you should identify wasteful usage of memory in your code base, and improve on that.
- Then, you should learn the fundamentals of GC (which you have already accomplished).
- Once you've learned it, you should start monitoring those vital statistics, in all environments - development, test, and production.
- When those vital statistics indicate that your project could potentially suffer from a GC problem, use the techniques learned to isolate the cause, and/or apply one or more mitigations to keep the problem under control.

---

What are some of the things that could be tuned?

Just a few examples - pardon if my examples are wrong.

- Tune the hardware (RAM sizes)
- Tune the OS
- Tune the JVM or GC
- Tune your project in the way it uses (generating and maintaining) long-living objects, if such objects collectively account for a significant fraction of overall memory usage.